# RadioButton.setChecked() doesn't appear to work

Tags: java, android, string, if-statement, radio-button

This is the code in my arrayadapter that will set the RadioButtons status:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        attendance_holder holder = null;
        People_Attendance people_array[] = people_attendance.toArray(new People_Attendance[people_attendance.size()]);
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new attendance_holder();
            holder.txtName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name_txt);
            holder.txtNumber = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.number_txt);
            holder.attendance_group = row.findViewById(R.id.Attendance_Group);
            holder.not_attending = (RadioButton) holder.attendance_group.findViewById(R.id.not_attending_radio);
            holder.attending = (RadioButton) holder.attendance_group.findViewById(R.id.attending_radio);
            holder.invited = (RadioButton) holder.attendance_group.findViewById(R.id.invited_radio);


            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (attendance_holder)row.getTag();
        }


        holder.txtName.setText(people_array[position].name);
        holder.txtNumber.setText(people_array[position].number);
        if (people_array[position].attendance_status == "INVITED"){
            holder.invited.setChecked(true);
        }else if(people_array[position].attendance_status == "ATTENDING"){
            holder.attending.setChecked(true);
        }else if(people_array[position].attendance_status == "NOT ATTENDING"){
            holder.not_attending.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            Log.d("ATTENDANCE", people_array[position].attendance_status);
        }


        return row;

    }
```

I have used the Log.d() in my code to show the string, so I know it's not an empty string or bad string that's the problem. I would therefore think that either my if statements are wrong in someway, or that I am using RadioButton.setChecked() wrong. Then RadioButtons then do not get checked in the way they should do. The RadioButtons are in a RadioGroup.

Any thoughts??

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: post complete getView code

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @Reimeus quite possibly, but I didn't realize that was the problem in the question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compare `Strings` using the `=` operator in Java. Use `equals()` instead. While using `=` compiles fine, it just compares the *memory addresses*, which certainly is not what you want.

Eg this:

```
people_array[position].attendance_status == "INVITED"
```

Should be:

```
people_array[position].attendance_status.equals("INVITED");
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks for the help!! So can "==" operator only be used for integers and booleans?? Is it because strings are objects, and not primitives?? thanks! :)

Comment: Exactly, it's because Strings are no primitives. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(people_array[position].attendance_status.equals("INVITED")
```

use this instead of

```
people_array[position].attendance_status == "INVITED"
```

You can simplify the code as below.

```
holder.invited.setChecked(people_array[position].attendance_status.equals("INVITED"));
holder.attending.setChecked(people_array[position].attendance_status.equals("ATTENDING"));
holder.not_attending.setChecked(people_array[position].attendance_status.equals("NOT ATTENDING"));
```

Comment: Nice simplification! Thanks!:)

Answer (score 1):

This is the code you should be using. You cannot compare strings like that. You have to use the .equals() function.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    attendance_holder holder = null;
    People_Attendance people_array[] = people_attendance.toArray(new People_Attendance[people_attendance.size()]);
    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new attendance_holder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name_txt);
        holder.txtNumber = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.number_txt);
        holder.attendance_group = row.findViewById(R.id.Attendance_Group);
        holder.not_attending = (RadioButton) holder.attendance_group.findViewById(R.id.not_attending_radio);
        holder.attending = (RadioButton) holder.attendance_group.findViewById(R.id.attending_radio);
        holder.invited = (RadioButton) holder.attendance_group.findViewById(R.id.invited_radio);


        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (attendance_holder)row.getTag();
    }


    holder.txtName.setText(people_array[position].name);
    holder.txtNumber.setText(people_array[position].number);
    if (people_array[position].attendance_status.equals("INVITED")){
        holder.invited.setChecked(true);
    }else if(people_array[position].attendance_status.equals("ATTENDING")){
        holder.attending.setChecked(true);
    }else if(people_array[position].attendance_status.equals("NOT ATTENDING")){
        holder.not_attending.setChecked(true);
    }else{
        Log.d("ATTENDANCE", people_array[position].attendance_status);
    }


    return row;

}
```